# geting the html of tables with greater than 4 rows stored in an array map(function()

Tags: jquery

With the following code in jquery:

```
  $(source).children('table').filter(function() {
return ($('tbody > tr', 'table').length >= 4)})
```

I filter out tables that have 4 rows or greater. I'm trying to create an array of the html from this using the map (function() but this doesn't seem to work. Im trying to get the html() of each table that satisfies this condition.

Comment: What result are you getting back?

Comment: I'm not getting anything when I try to put a border around the table of index[0]....(for test purposes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$(source).children("table").map(function() {
    if ($("tbody > tr", this).length >= 4) {
        return $(this).html();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}).get();
```

[Selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) in jQuery expects a DOM element, jQuery, or document. Using `this` will restrict the query to the element being evaluated in the `filter` function.

Comment: yes but I want to create an array of each table's html content.

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlArray = $('#source').children('table')
                            .filter(function() {
                                return ($('tbody > tr', $(this)).length >= 4);
                          }).map(function(i, item) {
                                return $(item).html();
                          }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in the [`map()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method.

```
var arr = $(source).children('table').map(function() {
    if( $('tbody > tr', this).length >= 4 ) return $(this).html();
}).get();
```

Or using the [`jQuery.map()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method.

```
var arr = $.map($(source).children('table'), function(val,i) {
    if( $('tbody > tr', val).length >= 4 ) return $(this).html();
});
```